# Outlook VSTO ribbon to home tabControlId

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, vsto

I'm writing a [VSTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) [Microsoft Outlook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook) plug-in. The version destination of that plugin is Outlook 2007 and 2010, so I use the Outlook 2007 add-in (in Visual Studio).

I have some (visual) problem with ActiveMenuBar. In Outlook 2007 it works fine, but in 2010 the ActiveMenuBar doesn't exist; it is replaced with tabControl and ribbons.

I would like to check the version (`Application.Version`) and if the version is 14 (Outlook 2010) then don't add an item into ActiveMenuBar, but add a ribbon to the **Home** tabPage.

How do I add the Ribbon into the **Home** tab page? For example, if I add a ribbon to the **Message** tab page, I set the `ribbonControl.OfficeId` to "TabReadMessage", but I can't find the OfficeId of the **Home** tab.

Answer (score 10):

Set the 'ControlId' property (ribbon designer properties) or the idMso (ribbon XML) to TabHome (**Edit**: `TabMail` *in Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013*). The ribbongroups on your ribbon will then be added to the existing Home ribbon.

A complete list of all other ribbon names can be found in *[2007 Office System Document: Lists of Control IDs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3582)* and in *[Office 2010 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6627)*.

Comment: In Outlook 2010 the Home tab has the id TabMail

Comment: In Outlook 2013 in my experience it also turned out to be TabMail for the HOME tab

Answer (score 2):

set Controllid "TabNewMailMessage" and Select Ribbon Type form Outlook.mail.Compose.Then you will get a addin in compose mail tab

Comment: `<tab idMso="TabNewMailMessage">` Worked for Outlook 2019. Thanks.