# Outlook addin Home tab with custom button

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-addin, ribbon

Hey all I am trying to create a button within the default **Home** tab in Outlook 2010. Problem being is that, in VS2013 I added a Ribbon (visual) and added the group with the button but it keeps adding that to the **TabAddIns** tab.

[image]

[image]

What do I need to set in order for that custom group/button to display in the **Home** tab instead of making its own tab?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the following question is related (one answer, also read the comment). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812966/outlook-vsto-ribbon-to-home-tabcontrolid

Comment: If you are interested please commit for this : stackoverflow.com/documentation/outlook-addin/commit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got it!
[image]

Using **[this link here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)** is was able to figure out that the **Home** tab was called **TabMail**.
[image]

And following these directions:

A built-in tab is a tab that is already on the Ribbon of an Outlook Explorer or Inspector. In this procedure, you will add the custom group to a built-in tab, and then specify the position of the custom group on the tab.

**To add the custom group to a built-in tab**

Click the TabAddins (Built-In) tab to select it.

In the Properties window, expand the ControlId property, and then set OfficeId to TabMail.

This adds the Customer Purchases group to the Messages tab of the Ribbon that appears in a new mail message.

Click the Customer Purchases group to select it.

In the Properties window, expand the Position property, click the drop-down arrow next to the PositionType property, and then click BeforeOfficeId.

Set the OfficeId property to Find.

This positions the Customer Purchases group before the Clipboard group of the Messages tab.

Comment: Great answer, helped me a lot.  Does this also work if the ribbon/tab group was created with visual designer?  I was following this tutorial, and I want to move my button out of the Add-ins tab and to the  home tab.  I can change where it appears with ribbon type, but I want the button to display in the Home tab for all message actions, rather than in its own tab.

Comment: Works fine with visual designer.  Make sure to use docs for your verison of office as they change slightly.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  I see it in the correct place but it is greyed out.