# Outlook AddIn not displayed in Message Tab

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook-addin

I have created a Outlook Addin which is added to Home Tab in Outlook.
I followed the below link :
[Outlook addin Home tab with custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247405/outlook-addin-home-tab-with-custom-button)

It is working fine in **Home** Tab, but when I see the particular mail in a new window i.e **Message** Tab, the Addin is not visible.

Below are screenshot for the same (Green color Create Note)

[image]

But after I double click the mail, the button is not displayed in **Message** Tab:

[image]

I require to copy the mail body when I click the CreateNote button, So I need that button also in **Message** Tab.

Any suggestion ?

**Solution:**

After input from below and analysis I found it's better to create two separate ribbon :

one for **Home** Tab(set ribbon type to outlook.explorer) and another for **message** Tab(set ribbon type to outlook.mail.read) and I have to set **OfficeId** of **Ribbon** Tab **different** (for Explorer-->TabMail and for Read-->TabReadMessage)

It solved my problem...

Thank u everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose appropriate values for the **RibbonType** property:

[image]

- Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose
  or
- Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read

Comment: Thanks buddy...for this input...Although it is not the solution for me,but It helped me a lot :) I have put the solution above.